# Movie about a girl or boy with telekinesis who is kept in control facilities

Tags: story-identification, movie, powers, telekinesis

I remember watching this movie around 2010–2015; that's my guess.

It is about a girl, or it could be about a girl with telekinesis who is kept in control facilities (most likely government) who are interested in her telekinetic skills and use them for themselves.

She will only speak with one man she trusts.

In the last scene, the kid plays chess with the only person she trusted.

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[Prodigy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5017936/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (2017)...?

> A psychologist engages a dangerous, young genius in a battle of wits -- unaware of the supernatural power the girl possesses, or that her life hangs in the balance.

Ellie, a highly articulate nine-year-old with telekinetic abilities, is being held in a secure facility. She claims credit for having murdered her mother and is regarded as a sociopath and a threat to national security. There's growing pressure for her to be executed and dissected for scientific analysis, but Agent Olivia Price, the woman in charge of the facility, calls in Dr. James Fonda, a psychologist and an old friend from college, to see if he can make sufficient progress with Ellie to grant her a stay of execution. He and Ellie have a series of conversations in an observation room, and they play a game of chess on a chess board he brought with him; Ellie moves the pieces with her mind.

In the closing scene, they play another game of chess by a lake, with security personnel watching from a distance. Without going into spoilers more than I already have, I think it'd be accurate to say that Ellie trusts Fonda by this point.

> [image: Image of Dr. Fonda and Ellie playing a game of chess by a lake, from "Prodigy" (2017).]
>
> <sub>*Prodigy* (2017)</sub>

Comment: and definitely not to be confused with "The Prodigy" from a few years later.